# Line spacing with Latex

Tags: latex

hallo i am using latex for my thesis writing. and i have facing problem with extra blank line space.. i am wondering about that even if i don't make any extra space in code, i saw many extra spacing while seeing in pdf generated by same code..
For example, i need this

this is my thesis and it will be finished soon. the topic of this thesis is very interesting.

and i get this,

```
 this is my  thesis   and  it will   be   finished soon.   the   topic of this thesis is very         
     interesting.
```

so please give me idea about this extra spaces problem, where do in code i should make changes??

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is. Is this extra horizontal space between words? Is the right-hand margin straight or ragged? Is it a particularly narrow column? Are you getting many error messages in the `.log` file? Perhaps if you can show a sample page, the problem might be obvious.

Comment: Can you please post any code that can be compiled (preamble and some lines of text from the contents showing the issue) or at least a screenshot of the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX forces a straight right margin for completed lines, so it will space your words out to achieve that. You can tell it to hyphenate words instead by inserting `\-` into any hyphenation locations in the word you want to break, e.g. `this is my thesis and it will be finished soon. the topic of this the\-sis is very inter\-es\-ting.`. You can also tell it to be a little sloppier with the sloppypar environment: `\begin{sloppypar}this is my thesis and it will be finished soon. the topic of this thesis is very interesting.\end{sloppypar}`

Comment: thanks for answer but i have 100 pages written in latex and every line has same problem. The margin of the thesis is set to automated spaces or something like that. so to changing whole draft to normal spacing what should i change in packages